# Human gastric lipase

Tags: biochemistry

Does anyone know if the human gastic lipase has a quaternary structure? If not, why not? I can not seem to find this information anywhere.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it might be better asked in a biochemistry group.

Comment: I think the question should be reopened because the OP addressed a real gap in the available information on this protein. I have since edited the images on Wikipedia and Proteopedia - we will see if these edits stick.

Answer (score 2):

There is a crystal structure of human gastric lipase ([PDB ID 1hlg](https://www.rcsb.org/structure/1hlg)). The accompanying [paper](http://www.jbc.org/content/274/24/16995.long) does not mention any quaternary structure and shows the protein as single chain. [Automated analysis](http://www.eppic-web.org/ewui/#id/1hlg) of the coordinates support that. The enzyme is glycosylated, so the molar mass does not match the one expected from the sequence. The apparent molar mass determined [experimentally](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/002228369291032K) is about 50,000 g/mol, corresponding to a monomer.

However, the annotation in the structure (probably erroneously) say that the biological assembly consists of the two chains in the asymmetric unit. Also, there is a [report](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/7126632) that the size of the molecule changes with pH (90,000 g/mol at pH 6 vs 45000 g/mol at pH 3).

The same group that solved the human lipase structure later solved the dog lipase structure (in an open conformation with a bound ligand) where the annotation in the PDB deposition says it is a monomer. I doubt that there are interspecies differences between dog and human in terms of quaternary structure, so that would be another piece of evidence supporting that the human enzyme is a monomer in its native form.

Comment: @Leigh Keep in mind you can also [accept](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) answers that were useful to you.